How can I make the output of my excel like this?
is there any possible way I can output the excel file to be like this. (Image below)
In my front side, I have a choice to pick year or month, but currently I'm just focusing in the month.
So what I did is export an array of object wherein it has a key of year, month , day and counts. The counts means is the data is during the day.
export-to-csv/route.ts
const getHistoryDataSchema = z.object({
  timeframe: z.enum(['month', 'year']),
  month: z.coerce.number().min(0).max(11).default(0),
  year: z.coerce.number().min(2000).max(3000)
})
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)
  const timeframe = searchParams.get('timeframe')
  const year = searchParams.get('year')
  const month = searchParams.get('month')
 
  const queryParams = getHistoryDataSchema.safeParse({
    timeframe,
    year,
    month
  })
 
  if (!queryParams.success) {
    return Response.json(queryParams.error.message, {
      status: 400
    })
  }
 
  try {
    const data = await getZoomReportData(
      queryParams.data.timeframe, {
      month: queryParams.data.month,
      year: queryParams.data.year
    }
    )
 
    return Response.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json(error)
  }
 
}
 
async function getZoomReportData(
  timeframe: TimeFrame, period: Period
) {
  switch (timeframe) {
    case "year":
      return getYearZoomData(period.year)
    case "month":
      return await getMonthZoomData(period.year, period.month)
  }
}
 
interface HistoryData {
  year: number;
  month: number;
  day?: number;
  counts?: DepartmentCounts;
}
 
interface DepartmentCounts {
  UNIT_1: number;
  UNIT_2: number;
  UNIT_3: number;
  UNIT_4: number;
  UNIT_5: number;
  UNIT_6: number;
  UNIT_7: number;
  UNIT_8: number;
  UNIT_9: number;
  UNIT_10: number;
  UNIT_11: number;
  UNIT_12: number;
  UNIT_13: number;
  UNIT_14: number;
  UNIT_15: number;
}
 
async function getYearZoomData(year: number) {
  // Implementation for year data fetching
}
 
async function getMonthZoomData(year: number, month: number) {
  const departments = [
    'UNIT_1', 'UNIT_2', 'UNIT_3', 'UNIT_4', 'UNIT_5', 'UNIT_6', 'UNIT_7',
    'UNIT_8', 'UNIT_9', 'UNIT_10', 'UNIT_11', 'UNIT_12', 'UNIT_13', 
    'UNIT_14', 'UNIT_15'
  ];
 
  const results = await Promise.all(
    departments.map(department =>
      db.scheduleDate.groupBy({
        by: ['day'],
        where: {
          year,
          month,
          soft_delete_scheduleDate: false,
          appointment: {
            soft_delete: false,
            department
          }
        },
        orderBy: [{ day: 'asc' }],
        _count: { _all: true },
      })
    )
  );
 
  const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
 
  const history: HistoryData[] = Array.from({ length: daysInMonth }, (_, i) => {
    const day = i + 1;
    const counts: DepartmentCounts = {
      UNIT_1: 0,
      UNIT_2: 0,
      UNIT_3: 0,
      UNIT_4: 0,
      UNIT_5: 0,
      UNIT_6: 0,
      UNIT_7: 0,
      UNIT_8: 0,
      UNIT_9: 0,
      UNIT_10: 0,
      UNIT_11: 0,
      UNIT_12: 0,
      UNIT_13: 0,
      UNIT_14: 0,
      UNIT_15: 0,
    };
 
    departments.forEach((department, index) => {
      const dayData = results[index].find(item => item.day === day);
      counts[department as keyof DepartmentCounts] = dayData ? dayData._count._all : 0;
    });
 
    return { year, month, day, counts };
  });
 
  return history;
}

And this will be the result of my json file
[
    {
        "year": 2024,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 1,
        "counts": {
            "UNIT_1": 0,
            "UNIT_2": 0,
            "UNIT_3": 0,
            "UNIT_4": 0,
            "UNIT_5": 0,
            "UNIT_6": 0,
            "UNIT_7": 1,
            "UNIT_8": 0,
            "UNIT_9": 0,
            "UNIT_10": 0,
            "UNIT_11": 0,
            "UNIT_12": 0,
            "UNIT_13": 0,
            "UNIT_14": 0,
            "UNIT_15": 0,
            "UNIT_16": 0,
            "UNIT_17": 0,
            "UNIT_18": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "year": 2024,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 2,
        "counts": {
            "UNIT_1": 0,
            "UNIT_2": 0,
            "UNIT_3": 0,
            "UNIT_4": 0,
            "UNIT_5": 0,
            "UNIT_6": 0,
            "UNIT_7": 1,
            "UNIT_8": 0,
            "UNIT_9": 0,
            "UNIT_10": 0,
            "UNIT_11": 0,
            "UNIT_12": 0,
            "UNIT_13": 0,
            "UNIT_14": 0,
            "UNIT_15": 0,
            "UNIT_16": 0,
            "UNIT_17": 0,
            "UNIT_18": 0
        }
    },
 ...//rest of the day
]



You can use Power Query in Excel to import the JSON and then configure it as you show in your results

Hello @RonRosenfeld, I'm trying to make it automated, i should output the excel when I click the button,

That I cannot help you with.
